# Google cloud functions : All criteria for calling Http triggered cloud functions from outside cloud project (browser or c# client)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have written Google cloud function (HTTP trigger). It tests successfully within the google cloud interface. Now I need to call it from Unity Game (C# .Net core).

1. First I tried to run it from browser. I took URL shown in Google cloud function interface. It does not work. I do not get stackdriver log (it does not even hit the URL?). 
   Is it because it needs oauth 2.0 token?
2. I am creating Http request , embedding JSON

   ```
   request.ContentType = "application/json";
   request.Method = "POST";
   request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
   //token obtained from oauth 2.0 JWT call
   byte[] JsonContentBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strjsonReqContent);
   // my Json object. requestJSON.ToString());
   request.ContentLength = JsonContentBytes.Length;
   ```

Here I tried with Oauth 2.0 token as well. (It works for storage API. My service account for cloud function has project editor access)

I saw one post about using cloud function from outside the cloud project. It did not solve my problem.

Please let me know all the criteria for using cloud functions from outside the cloud project.

EDIT1:

Thanks for the suggestion. Here is the log from Curl execution. I am not used to web debugging. Please suggest what should I check further. I could make out that it is 'Bad Request'. The URL is the one I picked from cloud function console.

```
>curl -v -X POST https://us-central1- myproject.cloudfunctions.net/myfunctiontest -H "Content-Type:application/json"  -d '{"username":"myemail@mydomain.com","password":"password1"}'
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 172.217.163.174...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to us-central1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net (172.217.163.174) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with us-central1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net port 443 (step 1/3)
* schannel: checking server certificate revocation
* schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 212 bytes...
* schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 212 bytes
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with us-central1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with us-central1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 4096
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4096 length 4096
* schannel: encrypted data length: 4028
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4028 length 4096
* schannel: received incomplete message, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with us-central1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 1024
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 5052 length 5052
* schannel: received incomplete message, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with us-central1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 1024
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 6076 length 6076
* schannel: received incomplete message, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with us-central1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 1024
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 7100 length 7100
* schannel: received incomplete message, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with us-central1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 1024
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 8124 length 8124
* schannel: received incomplete message, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with us-central1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 317
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 8441 length 9148
* schannel: sending next handshake data: sending 93 bytes...
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with us-central1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 284
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 284 length 9148
* schannel: SSL/TLS handshake complete
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with us-central1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net port 443 (step 3/3)
* schannel: stored credential handle in session cache
> POST /logontest HTTP/1.1
> Host: us-central1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:application/json
> Content-Length: 59
>
* upload completely sent off: 59 out of 59 bytes
* schannel: client wants to read 102400 bytes
* schannel: encdata_buffer resized 103424
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: encrypted data got 506
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 506 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 477
* schannel: decrypted data added: 477
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 477 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 477 length 102400
* schannel: schannel_recv cleanup
* schannel: decrypted data returned 477
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 102400
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Type: text/html
< Function-Execution-Id: qyx8g4vv8hn1
< X-Cloud-Trace-Context: 6f8012ea791b4a0f900ac4b84debaf5f;o=1
< Date: Thu, 02 May 2019 13:23:14 GMT
< Server: Google Frontend
< Content-Length: 192
< Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,44,43,39"
<
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
 <title>400 Bad Request</title>
 <h1>Bad Request</h1>
 <p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not 
  understand.</p>
 * Connection #0 to host us-central1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net left intact
```

The 'bad request' may not be due to URL since I took from the cloud function UI. Please suggest how I should proceed. Thanks.

Comment: Try using curl with the -v (verbose) flag, for example `curl -v mycloudurl` and see if there are client-side error messages. Perhaps there's a problem with the TLS handshake, for example. If there are no client-side errors, then it should be hitting your function; check your logs. If it is, then there's something wrong with your client code, not the cloud function.

Comment: When testing an endpoint in the browser, press F-12 to enable the debugger window. What messages are displayed in the "console" and "network" tabs?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried Curl and appended the log to my question. Please check and let me know.